# Java Syntax error?

Tags: java, syntax-error

So I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, I'm extremely new to programming and my school is online so I'm on my own. Based on my book, this code should work? I keep getting the error

"Syntax Error on tokens, Expression expected instead" //line 11 

 `if (cities [ i ][ j ].charAt (0) ==`**`'S'`**`)`

the "S" is bolded because Eclipse is showing the error there

If someone could point me in the right direction, I would be most appreciative! Thanks!

```
public class week6{
    public static void main (String [] args){
        for(int i = 0; i < cities.length; i++){ 
            for (int j = 0; j < cities [ i ] .length; j++){ 
                if(cities[ i ][ j ].charAt(0) == ‘S’) 
                    System.out.println(cities [ i ][ j ]); 
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: `‘` is not a valid quote. Try with `'`.

Comment: I'm guessing that you copy pasted from some site, and most probably from some word editor, change ‘S’ to 'S' (‘ and ’ are not valid)

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
if ( cities [ i ][ j ].charAt ( 0 ) == ‘S’ )
```

with

```
if ( cities [ i ][ j ].charAt ( 0 ) == 'S' )
```

`‘` and `’` are different from `'`. The compiler complains because it doesn't recognize the curly apostrophes. Use normal apostrophes to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your aphostrophe with `'`
So it would be

```
public class week6

    {
        public static void main (String[] args)
        {
        for ( int i = 0; i < cities.length; i++ ) 
    { 
        for ( int j = 0; j < cities [ i ] .length; j++ ) 
        { 
            if ( cities [ i ][ j ].charAt ( 0 ) == 'S' ) 
            System .out.println ( cities [ i ][ j ] ) ; 
        } 
    } 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like other has mentioned use  `'` instead of `’` and `‘`.

Or use `if (cities[i][j].startsWith("S"))` instead of  `if (cities[i][j].charAt(0) == 'S')`.

```
public class week6 {

    private static String[][] cities = {{"somecity1", "Somecity2"}, {"somecity3", "Somecity4"}};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cities[i].length; j++) {
                if (cities[i][j].startsWith("S")) { //or  if (cities[i][j].charAt(0) == 'S') 
                    System.out.println(cities[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```